# Redirect to php script using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

For a web-application I would like to rewrite the URL.

From:

```
http://example.com/api/logger/all
```

To:

```
http://example.com/api/index.php/logger/all
```

So I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php/  
RewriteRule ^api(.*)$ api/index.php$1 [L]
```

I also testet it successfully with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.

On the server I get a 404.

My project struct looks like following:

```
--api
----index.php
--htaccess
--index.html
```

### **Update:**

I found a solution for external redirects.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/index.php/$1 [R=302]
```

But I need a internal redirect and if remove [R=302] I get 404 with "No input file specified." as response.
Following htaccess file works for 
    http://example.com/logger/all.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/index.php/$1
```

But adding **api** again results in "No input file specified."

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^api(.*)$ /api/index.php/$1
```

Comment: That looks okay, so what's the problem now.?

Comment: What is generating the "No input file specified." error? That isn't an Apache error, so it would seem to be your script that is generating that error? Your last ruleset would result in a double slash - is that a problem for your script? You should either change `^api(.*)$` to `^api/(.*)$` (your redirect "that works" contains the slash), or remove the slash in the substitution. But you should probably also use the `L` flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mod_rewrite is a double-edged sword that is incredibly easy to misuse.

Apache 2.2.16 and later provide the extremely useful but surprisingly seldom used [`FallbackResource`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) directive.

So use the following layout:

```
--api
----.htaccess
----index.php
--index.html
```

And use the following contents for your .htaccess file:

```
FallbackResource /api/index.php
```

The main difference with the mod_rewrite based solutions is that there is no substitution in the URI, so you have to parse the URI in PHP using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

For example here, if you access `http://example.com/api/logger/all`, your `index.php` file will see the following value:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // prints /api/logger/all
```

The main interest of putting the `.htaccess` file in the `api` directory is that it ensures that only URLs under the `/api` prefix are handled by `FallbackResource`. Any URL that would cause a 404 error in the document root folder will not trigger a call to `/api/index.php`.

Comment: The only problem is that by adding this FallbackResource /api/index.php, the content of the index gets printed on the page if accessed like this: /api/index